# Is there an intuitive or logical explanation for this identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw this identity somewhere and I'm wondering if there's a more intuitive explanation for this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2k-1 = n^2$$

I know how to verify it algebraically by simplifying the left side but is there another way to think about this? Could the fact that the derivative of $n^2=2n$ has something to do with it? What significance does it have, if any?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/639079/30382

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136237/direct-proof-that-1-3-5-cdots-2n-1-n-cdot-n